# Using $in on multiple object ids

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am running into problems deriving the correct MongoDB query. I am trying to formulate a query using the find operation that will retrieve multiple specified ids at once. Note that I cannot use ObjectId() functions. I need to use plain operators like $or, $and, $in, etc.

The dataset in MongoDB has rows that look like the following:

```
{
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "123"
 },
 "someField": "hello"
 ...
}
{
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "456"
 },
 "someField": "hello"
 ...
}
```

I have been able to use $or successfully in the following way, but since the MongoDB documentation suggests using $in over $or in terms of performance, I'd like to know how to do this using $in:

```
{ $or: [{ "_id": {   "$oid": "123"   }  },{ "_id": {   "$oid": "456"}}]}
```

I have tried the following queries, but none of them have returned any results:

```
{ "_id":  { $in: ["123", "456"] } }
{ "_id": { $in: [  "$oid": "123","$oid": "456"  ]} } 
{ "_id.$oid":  { $in: ["123", "456"]  }   }
```

As a last note, I cannot use any queries that completely isolate the object ids, as I am querying for the "someField" field of every matched object id as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it :

```
{ "_id": { $in: [  "$oid": "123","$oid": "456"  ]} } 
should read
{ "_id":{ $in:[{"$oid":"123"},{"$oid":"456"}]}}
```

You pass in an array but because you are searching the `_id` field you need to send `{"$oid":"oid_value"}` for each item